# Instalação do PHPUnity SkeletonGenerator exige ConsoleTools

Tags: php, tdd

Ao tentar instalar o SkeletonGenerator, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
servidor@ubuntu$ sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator
[sudo] password for servidor: 
Unknown remote channel: components.ez.no
phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator requires package "channel://components.ez.no/ConsoleTools" (version >= 1.6)
No valid packages found
install failed
```

Comment: Eu publico uma pergunta com minha resposta para compartilhar conhecimento se alguém tiver o mesmo problema que eu e alguém vem e me negativa. Tem alguma coisa errada aqui? Então comenta, P****!

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver eu incluí o canal da dependência:

```
servidor@ubuntu$ sudo pecl channel-discover components.ez.no

Adding Channel "components.ez.no" succeeded
Discovery of channel "components.ez.no" succeeded
```

E então instalei o Skeleton:

```
servidor@ubuntu$ sudo pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator

downloading PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator-1.2.1.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator-1.2.1.tgz (11,376 bytes)
.....done: 11,376 bytes
downloading ConsoleTools-1.6.1.tgz ...
Starting to download ConsoleTools-1.6.1.tgz (869,994 bytes)
...done: 869,994 bytes
downloading Base-1.8.tgz ...
Starting to download Base-1.8.tgz (236,357 bytes)
...done: 236,357 bytes
install ok: channel://components.ez.no/Base-1.8
install ok: channel://components.ez.no/ConsoleTools-1.6.1
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator-1.2.1
```